# Keycloak rest api wrapper with spring boot 2.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to create a micro service that wraps over some of the Keycloak API endpoints with a swagger ui but as I add keycloak, I can't start the app.

If I don't add the adapter dependency that doesn't work either.

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-services', version: '4.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '4.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-spring-boot-adapter', version: '4.0.0.Final'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b764bce]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:726) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:889) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:875) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:810) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.safetonet.security.api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3139) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2266) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496) ~[na:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had to update the spring boot dependency to webflux version as it supports undertow to make it work.

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.0.0.RELEASE")
    compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-services', version: '4.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '4.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-authz-client', version: '4.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jackson2-provider', version: '4.0.0.Beta4'
```